# Chocolatey installed package not on Path

Tags: windows-7, chocolatey

I've been installing programs with chocolatey, but it's not adding them to my path automatically. Does anyone know a solution? I just followed the install instruction on Chocolatey's front page, and everything works well. The programs just aren't being added to the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you install, and whether those native installers add themselves to the path in some cases.

If the package maintainer doesn't take the extra step in the cases where the installer doesn't add a program folder to the PATH, then those items may not be available on the command line.

The other side of this is that those items may be in PATH, but not to your current shell (cmd/powershell/whatever). This is due to how Windows works versus terminal in *nix. We've made some improvements there but it's not perfect. Expect things to get better over time in that aspect.

We have one issue out for ensuring that we create the User PATH correctly in the registry. This might be what is causing the issue for any items that may be adding themselves to this PATH instead of the system PATH.